# How To Add A Back Slash To The TextBox For Date Format

Tags: javascript, date, textbox, backslash, maskedtextbox

This Is My JavaScript:

`

```
function ValidateDate(txt, keyCode)
        {
            if(keyCode==16)
                isShift = false;
            var val=txt.value;
            var lblmesg = document.getElementById("<%=lblMesg.ClientID%>") ;
            if(val.length == 10)
            {
                var splits = val.split("/");
                var dt = new Date(splits[1] + "/" + splits[0] + "/" + splits[2]);

                //Validation for Dates
                if(dt.getDate()==splits[0] && dt.getMonth()+1==splits[1] && dt.getFullYear()==splits[2])
                {
                    lblmesg.style.color="green";
                    lblmesg.innerHTML = "Valid Date";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmesg.style.color="red";
                    lblmesg.innerHTML = "InValid Date";
                    return;
                } 

                //Range Validation
                if(txt.id.indexOf("txtRange") != -1)
                    RangeValidation(dt);

                //BirthDate Validation
                if(txt.id.indexOf("txtBirthDate") != -1)                
                    BirthDateValidation(dt)
            }
            else if(val.length < 10)
            {
                lblmesg.style.color="blue";
                lblmesg.innerHTML = "Required dd/mm/yy format. Slashes will come up automatically.";
            }
        }`
```

And This Is My TextBox:

```
> <asp:TextBox ID="txtValidate" runat="server" MaxLength = "10" onkeyup = "ValidateDate(this, event.keyCode)" onkeydown = "return DateFormat(this, event.keyCode)"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to include a slash within a TextBox for typing a Date.. I don't want it to generate a slash while typing...it should be static when the page is loaded.... Is it possible to do that without using AjaxToolkit ???

Comment: Now C My Code #micnic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example for your purpose:

```
var date = document.getElementById('date');

date.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which),
        offset = date.selectionStart;

    if (/\d/.test(char) && offset < 8) {

        if (offset === 2 || offset === 5) {
            offset += 1;
        }
        date.value = date.value.substr(0, offset) + char + date.value.substr(offset + 1);
        date.selectionStart = date.selectionEnd = offset + 1;
    }

    if (!event.keyCode) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fgLw720/2/)

Answer (score 4):

I use this simple replace

```html
Date: <input name=x size=10 maxlength=10  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')">
```

[Try it with jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6mnpc1j/)

Comment: This allows for numbers that are not valid dates, ie. 99/99/9999, it also breaks when pressing two keys at once.

Comment: this is so simple and quick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version:

```
    $("#txtDate").keyup(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length == 2 || $(this).val().length == 5){
         $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
      }
   });
```